# Intersection of two sets of strings

Tags: java, intersection, hashset

My question is very simple, I know but Don't know why I got this problem. I jsut want to get the intersection of two sets of strings. Here is my code  for that:

```
public int estimatorSuccess(Set<String> set1, Set<String> set2) {
    Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(set1);
    intersection.retainAll(set2);
```

}
But the intersection is empty !!!
Could somebody please tell me what's wrong with that?[image]

Comment: Is this the correct "intersection" variable you are checking?

Comment: Do you think it's because set1 and set2 are keysets of two treeMaps? because intersection is a hashSet. But, it so weird as the keyset method of treeMap returns a Set.

Comment: This behaviour is strange indeed. Could you please post how you're testing this function ?

Comment: Can you please print both sets inside methods, I have tried at my end it's working fine.

Comment: @HimanUCC It will still work, even if a TreeSet is used. I believe you are checking an incorrect variable. Also recommend to clean the project and build it again. If needed close the IDE and reopen and execute again.

Comment: @JNL Actually I debug the code and the intersection is empty as you can see. The rest of my code is a bit complicated and would give you no extra info. just be aware that the method receives two sets that these sets are keysets of two TreeMap

Comment: @HimanUCC Print the keySet() of the TreeMaps inside the method and see if the data is present?

Comment: @JNL the data is shown in the picture. somebody else also ask me this. Is the picture visible for you? the data of two sets is shown in the picture

Comment: @HimanUCC Clean the solution and Compile it again. If needed try closing the IDE and restarting it again.

Comment: the problem is resolved. I just make two new objects in my  method for two sets and now it works. have no idea what is the reason for this behavior